# creat my Own message box in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i try to do my Own message-box in jQuery-mobile like this:

**work with jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery-mobile 1.4.2**

```
function createDialog(title, text) {
            return $("<div class='dialog' title='" + title + "'><p>" + text + "</p></div>")
            .dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Confirm": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

<button onclick="createDialog('Confirm deletion!', 'Do you really want to delete this package?')">press me</button>
```

i try this sample - but Nothing happens...

EDIT:

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/goldsoft/qd5dy4dy/5/

thsnk

Comment: I looks like you're returning before anything else happens ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qd5dy4dy/2/

You're code is fine, you just forget the libraries.

The dialog() method is from jQueryUI. The linked jsfiddle, above, just adds jquery and jqueryUI.

```
//This code is here because SO requires some code
function createDialog(title, text) {
            return $("<div class='dialog' title='" + title + "'><p>" + text + "</p></div>")
            .dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Confirm": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: i try this on  jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery-mobile 1.4.2 and Nothing happens. i update my question

Comment: This is one of those terrible dependency problems. Due to the importing procedure of jsfiddle, it's not quite enough to just select the boxes in this case. I've explicitly added a script tag to jqueryui, and it seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/qd5dy4dy/7/